# Prisma - Unknown field `XYZ`

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma2

I'm creating a system where every user has some role. After that, each role contains a list of permissions that drive logic in the application.

**Prisma schema (prisma version 4.1.1)** 
For that purpose I created this Prisma schema:

```
model Role {
  id          String              @id @default(cuid())
  name        String              @db.VarChar(255)
  permissions PermissionOnRoles[]
  users       User[]
}

model Permission {
  id          String              @id
  name        String              @db.VarChar(255)
  description String              @db.VarChar(255)
  roles       PermissionOnRoles[]
}

model PermissionOnRoles {
  role         Role       @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id]) @ignore
  roleId       String     
  permission   Permission @relation(fields: [permissionId], references: [id])
  permissionId String
  assignedAt   DateTime   @default(now()) @ignore
  assignedBy   String     @ignore

  @@id([roleId, permissionId])
}
```

**How DB looks like now:**
After I migrate this schema I added some DEV data to database and real table looks like this:
Role:
[image]
PermissionOnRoles
[image]
Permission
[image]

But when I try to query the role included permission with queries like:

```
await prisma.role.findMany({
   include: {
       permissions: true,
   },
});
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid `prisma.role.findMany()` invocation:

{
  include: {
    permissions: true,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~
?   users?: true,
?   _count?: true
  }
}


Unknown field `permissions` for include statement on model Role. Available options are listed in green. Did you mean `users`?
```

I basically get the same error if I try to open the Role table in Prisma Studio.

I'm not great at designing databases so the design of my database could be wrong, or maybe I just miss something really stupid but I am not able to find anything so I am up for any advice which can lead me to the right way.

**What I tried**:

- delete node modules
- update prisma & @prisma/client to latest version
- prisma migrate dev - to verify whatthe  is in schema is in table
- prisma generate - just to test everything.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to query from the connecting table which is permissionOnRoles in this case.
So this query should work for you

```js
  await prisma.permissionOnRoles.findMany({
    include: {
      permission: {
        include: {
          roles: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```